# How to apply raster stack object each layer?

Tags: r

I want to apply funtion on stack each layer and return a stack.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(vals=1:20,nrow=4,ncols=5)
r2 <- raster(vals=2:21,nrow=4,ncols=5)
r3 <- raster(vals=3:22,nrow=4,ncols=5)
stk <- stack(r1,r2,r3)
func <- function(x){
  calc(x,function(y){
    ifelse(y>10,0,y)
  })
}
```

I apply `func` on each layer by using `lapply`

```
lapply(stk,func)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘calc’ for signature ‘"integer", "function"’
```

It seems `lapply` slice `stk` as `stk[1]` `stk[2]`..., but the actual layer is `stk[[1]]`,`stk[[2]]`....

And use `stackApply`:

```
stackApply(stk,indices=1:3,fun=func)
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (na.rm = na.rm)
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can use `calc` alone:

```
stack(calc(stk, function(y) ifelse(y > 10, 0, y)))
# class       : RasterStack 
# dimensions  : 4, 5, 20, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
# resolution  : 72, 45  (x, y)
# extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# names       : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
# min values  :       0,       0,       0 
# max values  :      10,      10,      10
```

Comment: @Cobin, does it answer your question?